# Updates on which attributes are relevant for the "updated_at" timestamp that is returned from gitlab API?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am querying gitlab projects using REST calls to the [gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html) (Example URL: https://gitlab.domain.com/api/v4/projects/).

In the result, there is the timestamp field `updated_at`, which is supposed to show the last update of the shown project.

However, I discovered that not all fields of a project are reflected in the `updated_at` timestamp. For example, a change in the star count of a gitlab project will not update the `updated_at` timestamp.

Is this a intended behavior?
Does anyone know an exact documentation of the fields that are covered / uncovered by gitlab's `updated_at` timestamp?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the code](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/5dff2cd71c921b8528b98db8a7c79262851e9ad4/app/models/project.rb#L1662-1668) and some other resources:

1. `last_activity_at` describes when the most recent event in the project occurred.
2. `updated_at` describes when the project itself was last updated.

`last_activity_at` is updated based on [events](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/events.html) based on the [events model code](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/e567e26e5830d2b8ee0a329193158c1e82e6c67e/app/models/event.rb#L363).

`updated_at` is updated whenever changes are made to the project record in the database. As this is an ActiveModel thing, there is no definitive list because it depends on the implementation. Someone would need to audit the whole codebase to give you a definitive answer. Generally though it would be whenever the [projects table](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/5dff2cd71c921b8528b98db8a7c79262851e9ad4/db/structure.sql#L98) is updated for that particular project. However, it's not all project changes as some features such as [CI/CD project settings](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/5dff2cd71c921b8528b98db8a7c79262851e9ad4/db/structure.sql#L21607) are in a separate table.

Comment: Note: I'm looking at getting this added to the documentation in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/138002